# Is there a way to use datetime.date without a year?

Tags: python, datetime

The answer is probably no, but I hope you don't mind if I ask just to be sure. Can `datetime.date` objects be somehow used like this?

```
import datetime as dt
is_summer = dt.date(month=7, day=1) <= dt.date.today() < dt.date(month=8, day=31)  # wrong!
```

Currently, I'm transforming the `datetime.date` objects to `(month, day)` tuples wherever I mean "every year". I'm considering to completely abandon `datetime` and use just the tuples everywhere.

Comment: What about writing a function `my_date()` that will return a `tuple`?

Comment: @ettanany As I wrote I'm considering to represent all dates as tuples. I just expected to find the needed functionality in a module which promises: _"The datetime module supplies classes for manipulating dates and times in both simple and complex ways"_

Comment: Does @Alex's answer fit your needs? note that you can also override the built-in function `date` if you want to keep using it with the same name.

Comment: @ettanany Please see my comment under Alex's answer, I wrote my opinion there.

Answer (score 1):

Your current method sounds pretty good. You could also do:

```
def date_this_year(**kwargs):
    return dt.date(year=dt.date.today().year, **kwargs)

is_summer = date_this_year(month=7, day=1) <= dt.date.today() < date_this_year(month=8, day=31)
```

Comment: Your code seems to be good readable, +1 for this idea. However, care must be taken not to save and reuse date_this_year results, because they could become date_last_year. That's why it does not help me much - but may help other readers.